# How do I remove the promise and make it a normal array

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, nodes

In my JavaScript learning journey, I encountered a complex problem that lasted more than 24 hours to research and try several published solutions, but unfortunately, I did not succeed in solving my problem. Which tempted me to write this reply to solve this complex problem for me!

```js
class db{
    async findOne(search){
        try {
            const doc = this.collection.doc(search).get();
            return get.data()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(Error(red(error)).message);
            process.exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```js
Promise { <pending> }
```

What I really want is for the output to be done without using `then` and be like the following output:

```json
{
  name:'Johan',
  age:'15',
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `findOne` function ?

Comment: `return get.data()` what  is get referring to here, is it in scope?

Comment: Because `findOne` in your class is `async`, it's always going to return a Promise. You need to use await when you call `findOne()` on your instance such as `await dbInstance.findOne(...)` or use `.then()` to get the result

Comment: Please note that `dv.findOne` is an `async` function and will return a promise. So whatever you do within the function with `await` etc. - the returned result (--> what is `get.data()` and where was it defined?!?) will be a promise.

Comment: All async functions return a promise - that's how that feature in the language works.  So, your `findOne()` method will ALWAYS return a promise and the caller will need to use `.then()` or `await` on that promise to get the resolved value.

Answer (score 0):

Is this `this.collection.doc(search).get();` synchronous, i guess it's not.

so, `const doc = await this.collection.doc(search).get();`

this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use await it wait on the specifix line until it finish
Here you go!!

```
const doc = await this.collection.doc(search).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting arrays of promises you can resolve them by using `promise.All([Array of promises]);`

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
console.log(values);
});
```

for more information, you can go to [MMDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)